# How to group pandas rows whenever a certain cumsum threshold is crossed (restarting the cumsum for each new group)

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

I'd like help on grouping consecutive rows whenever a given cumsum threshold is crossed. The cumsum should also be restarted (to zero) when this threshold is crossed, as such:

```
Index  Values       Regular CumSum  Wanted CumSum  Wanted Column
1      0.0666666666    0.0666666666    0.000000    0.0
2      0.0238095238    0.0904761904    0.000000    1.0
3      0.0134146341    0.1038908246    0.000000    2.0
4      0.0210135970    0.1249044216    0.013414    2.0
5      0.0072639225    0.1321683441    0.000000    3.0
6      0.0158536585    0.1480220027    0.007263    3.0
7      0.0012004801    0.1492224829    0.000000    4.0
8      0.0144230769    0.1636455598    0.001200    4.0
9      0.0130331753    0.1766787351    0.015623    4.0
```

In this case the threshold is 0.02 (sorry for all the decimals).

- Any entry larger then the threshold should immediately form or close a group (such as the entries in index 1,2 and 4)
- Entry on index 3 is smaller than threshold so it waits for the next consecutive entry. If the next entry (individually or summed to index 3's value) crosses the threshold they form a new group, otherwise the next next entry will be included as well (in this case index 4's entry is larger than the threshold so a new group is formed).
- Entry 5 is smaller than the threshold of 0.02, but summing entry 6, makes them larger than 0.02, hence a group is closed.
- Entries 7,8 and 9 summed together are larger than 0.02, thus forming a group.
- ....

I was able of developing the following simple code to do achieve this but I was hoping someone could help me developing a faster method maybe utilizing the pandas library:

```
FinalList = [0]
index=0
cumsum = 0
i=1
#while to go through all entries in df
while(i!=df.index[-1]): 
    #When entry is larger(or equal) than threshold immediately close group and clear cumsum
    if df.Values.iloc[i] >= Threshold:
        FinalList.append(index)
        cumsum = 0
        index+=1
    #When entry is smaller than threshold
    if df.Values.iloc[i] < Threshold:
        #If previous cumsum plus current entry surpass threshold group is closed.       
        if cumsum + df.Values.iloc[i] > Threshold:
                FinalList.append(index)
                cumsum=0
                index+=1
            #Otherwise, continue increasing cumsum until it crosses threshold
            else:
                cumsum = cumsum + df.Values.iloc[i]
                FinalList.append(index)
        i+=1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54208023/can-i-perform-dynamic-cumsum-of-rows-in-pandas Seems like it should solve you question if performance is a big issue.

Comment: Thank you, with this answer and @P Maschhoff's, execution time was reduced to under a second!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining @P Maschoff's and @ALlolz's answers I developed the following code whose execution time (using a dataset with an execution time of over 15 seconds using the code in my original question) was reduced to under a second:

```
@njit
def dynamic_cumsum(seq, max_value):
    FinalList = [0]
    cumsum = 0
    running = 0
    for i in prange(len(seq)):
        cumsum += seq[i]
        if cumsum >= max_value:
            cumsum = 0
            running += 1        
        FinalList.append(running)
    return FinalList
```

Answer (score 1):

The more `pandas` way to do it is to iterate through a dataframe or column, like so:

```py
threshold = 0.02
cumsum = 0
group = 0
for idx, value in df.Values.iteritems():
    cumsum += value
    df.loc[idx, 'Group'] = group
    if cumsum >= threshold:
        cumsum = 0
        group += 1
```

```
         Values  Group
Index                 
1      0.066667    0.0
2      0.023810    1.0
3      0.013415    2.0
4      0.021014    2.0
5      0.007264    3.0
6      0.015854    3.0
7      0.001200    4.0
8      0.014423    4.0
9      0.013033    4.0
```

This isn't doing anything particularly fancy, but should be faster just because it makes fewer indexing operations, and operations in general. If you want to learn more about how to write `pandas` style code, I recommend [this](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1-intro.html) blog series by one of its developers.

Comment: Thank you! This reduced execution time to around 5 seconds but I was hoping to reduce even more the execution time, hopefully to the milliseconds (100's is acceptable)