# Fetch every n seconds rows from a pandas datetime column of a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

```
col1                      col2
2020-09-10 21:28:46       14
2020-09-10 21:28:47       13
2020-09-10 21:28:47       44
2020-09-10 21:28:48       11
2020-09-10 21:28:50       22
2020-09-11 21:28:51       33
2020-09-11 21:28:52       44
2020-09-11 21:28:53       45
2020-09-11 21:28:54       46
2020-09-11 21:28:55       32
2020-09-11 21:28:58       87
2020-09-11 21:29:01       98
2020-09-11 21:29:02       32
2020-09-11 21:29:02       12
2020-09-11 21:29:02       43
2020-09-11 21:29:05       34
```

The type of `col1` is pandas' `datetime`. Now, I want to fetch rows in every 5th second, if exact 5th second not found then fetch the next closest row. So the final data frame will look like:

```
col1                      col2
2020-09-10 21:28:46       14
2020-09-11 21:28:51       33
2020-09-11 21:28:58       87
2020-09-11 21:29:05       34
```

I could do this using a for loop and check the time difference with the previous row, but the execution will take more time. Looking for some pandas shortcuts to do the task most efficiently.

Comment: I think for loop is the way ~

Comment: Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54208023/can-i-perform-dynamic-cumsum-of-rows-in-pandas)